# Python Array Creation Using 2 other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, iterator

I have two arrays whose values i would like to use together in the creation of a third array. Below i have given the size and shapes of the arrays incase they can be of any help.

```
CV Shape = (126,)

RV Shape = (94,)

CV Size =126

RV Size =94
```

The array into which i want their values to be placed is defined as follows with the following code which i have tried to implement:

```
temp=np.empty((np.size(RV),np.size(CV)))

for i in CV[int(i)]:
    for j in RV[j]:
        temp[i,j]=(RV[i],CV[j])
```

This gives me a temp array with the following shape:
(94, 126)

The loop however does not work and I get the following error, does anyone have an idea of how to solve it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File 
"C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/TestImageRead/Normal/Camera/TurnerSystem/Project.py", line 47, in <module>

for i in CV[int(i)]:

TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

To give some further context and information, I am detecting dense optical flow in a video feed. RV and CV are horizontal and vertical positions of which i will sample the flow values from instead of using all of the values stored for each pixel. These points will effectively form a grid of sample points over the image.
From the OpenCV tutorials i was able to attain a magnitude array which stores the magnitude of flow at each of the pixels in the whole frame (640x480). So what i would like to do is to fill the temp array with the values of the magnitude at the points that are stored in RV and CV.

RV and CV store values like this:
[  5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55 ....]

So what i want to do is loop through all of the values of RV and CV and store the magnitude of each point of the image into the temp array for future use.

temp=mag(RV,CV)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `for i in CV[int(i)]` and `j in RV[j]`? Also, would be nice to see a minimal sample case and the expected output.

Comment: IIUC, with `mag` as the array from which elements are to be selected based on the row and column indices from `RV` and `CV`, you could just do : `mag[np.ix_(RV,CV)]`.

Comment: This can be done more effficiently, but to fix your existing code: in your `for` statements, you forgot to create an iterable to iterate over, and your use of `i` is not right.  You probably meant: `for i in range(CV.size):`

Answer (score 0):

The comments address the syntax change you'd need to make your loops work. A way to accomplish that final assignment with no looping uses `np.meshgrid`:

```
RR, CC = np.meshgrid(RV, CV, indexing='ij')
temp = mag[RR, CC]
```